# onItemClickListener(), how to pass clicked item's data?

Tags: android, list, onitemclicklistener

I am using onItemClickListener() with a List. I want to pass name of the item clicked on, and an arbitrary number to next instance of the list. How can this be done?
Edit: here is the class:

```
    public class ListViewA extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // create the grid item mapping
        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.item2};

        // prepare the list of all records
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("col_1", "col_1_item_" + i);
            fillMaps.add(map);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
        }

        // fill in the grid_item layout
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.grid_item, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(ListViewA.this,ListViewA.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

};
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you. What type of adapter are you using? Are you using a custom adapter?

Comment: please add more details for appropriate answer. post some of your code snippet for better help.

Comment: please add your itemclick method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following example shows you how to pass data onItemClick for particular position.

```
ListView lv = getListView();

            // listening to single list item on click
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

                  // selected item
                HERE YOU GOT POSITION FOR PERTICULAR ITEM

                  // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                  // sending data to new activity
                  i.putExtra("position", fillMaps.get(position));
                  startActivity(i);

              }
            });
```

And yes you need to declare `fillMaps` as globally.

```
public class ListViewA extends Activity{

    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);......
```

Comment: I am getting this error: fillMaps cannot be resolved. I think it's because Intent is in a different class.. How to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: @ankitrawat declare your fillMaps as globally.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent i=new Intent(ListViewA.this,ListViewA.class);
i.putExtra("Key", fillMaps.get(position));

startActivity(i);
```

You can use above code in your onItemClickListner.

Answer (score 0):

In this method the third agrument is position.  So you have to use this eg. The Arraylist you are  passing to your listView contains the data shown on listView. so use this kind of code

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String data=    mArrlist.get(position);
    }
```

If you are using the arralist of String type otherwise If you are using arraylist of getter setter class then use

```
  mArralist.get(potion).getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and how to pass the arbitrary number?

Comment: You can use Random class for this perpose.                            int random = mRandom.nextInt(mArrayList.size());

Answer (score 0):

You should get item @paticular position

```
HashMap<String, String> item = adapterview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

check your condition according to requirement and by getting data from `item` and process further.

```
Intent i=new Intent(ListViewA.this,ListViewA.class);
i.putExtra("item", item);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding arbitrary number you can use the Random class of java as below
    Random  mRandom = new Random();
    int random = mRandom.nextInt(mMoveToList.size());

random variable of int type return every time random value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getItem(int position)` of `SimpleAdapter`

1. put your SimpleAdapter variable `adapter` as global
2. in your ClickListener call `adapter.getItem(position)`